# There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key 'Userlist'

Tags: c#, sql-server, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-5

My User Model

```
    [Key]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [DisplayName("First Name")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [DisplayName("Last Name")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public virtual List<DptCRP> DptCRPs { get; set; }
```

My Patient Model

```
        [Key]
        [Required]
        [DisplayName("Registration No")]
        public string PatientRegNo { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [DisplayName("Patient Name")]
        public string PatientName { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [DisplayName("Father Name")]
        public string FatherName { get; set; }
        public string ReferDpt { get; set; }

        public virtual List<DptCRP> DptCRPs { get; set; }
```

My DptCRP Model(UserId nad PatientRegNo is used as Foreign key in this model)

```
    [Key]
    public int CRPId { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Provisional Diagnosis")]
    public string ProvisionalDiagnosis { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Progress Report")]
    public string ProgressReport { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string PatientRegNo { get; set; }
    public virtual Patient Patient { get; set; }
```

My Department Controller

```
[HttpGet]
    public ActionResult AddDptCRP()
    {
        var user = (from p in userdb.Users
                    where p.UserType == "doctor"
                    select p.UserId).ToList();
        ViewBag.Userlist = new SelectList(user, "UserId");
        var patient = (from p in patientdb.Patients
                    where p.ReferDpt == "dptcrp"
                    select p.PatientRegNo).ToList();
        ViewBag.Patientlist = new SelectList(patient, "PatientRegNo");
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AddDptCRP(DptCRP dptcrp)
    {
        try
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                dptdb.DptCRPs.Add(dptcrp);
                dptdb.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("ListDptCRP");
            }
            var user = (from p in userdb.Users
                        where p.UserType == "doctor"
                        select p.UserId).ToList();
            ViewBag.Userlist = new SelectList(user, "UserId");
            var patient = (from p in patientdb.Patients
                           where p.ReferDpt == "dptcrp"
                           select p.PatientRegNo).ToList();
            ViewBag.Patientlist = new SelectList(patient, "PatientRegNo");
            return View(dptcrp);
        }
        catch 
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

When i try to Add data in my DptCRP it shows error

> There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable' that has the key 'Userlist'

My AddDptCRP View Looks Like

```
@model FinalYear.Models.DptCRP
 @using (Html.BeginForm()) 
    {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>DptCRP</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ProvisionalDiagnosis, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ProvisionalDiagnosis, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ProvisionalDiagnosis, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
    <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ProgressReport, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ProgressReport, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ProgressReport, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserId, "UserId", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownList("Userlist", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PatientRegNo, "PatientRegNo", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownList("Patientlist", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PatientRegNo, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
}
```

Comment: Try using DropDownListFor with lambda that points to your Userlist, Patientlist instead. DropDownList tries to get these collections from ViewData by default, so yuo need to point to your viewmodel by your own instead

Comment: The error means that the value of `Userlist` is not a `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` You need to set the value of `ViewBag.Userlist` in the POST method before you return the view (your obviously hitting the `catch` block). Debug your code.

Comment: But since you creating an dropdownlist that does not bind to the `UserId` property of your model, its unclear what your expecting - your model will always be invalid - Your view should be `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.UserId, (SelectList)ViewBag.Userlist)` and ditto for `Patientlist`

Comment: Thanks @StephenMuecke

Answer (score 1):

The following query returns a list of int.

```
var user = (from p in userdb.Users
            where p.UserType == "doctor"
            select p.UserId).ToList();
```

The problem starts with the constructor you use

```
ViewBag.Userlist = new SelectList(user, "UserId");
```

This constructor

> Initializes a new instance of the SelectList class by using the
>   specified items for the list and a **selected value**.

Instead of using this constructor, you should use the following:

```
ViewBag.Userlist = new SelectList(user, "UserId", "UserId");
```

which

> Initializes a new instance of the SelectList class by using the
>   specified items for the list, the **data value field**, and the **data text**
>   **field**.

In your case, as it seems, the data value field and the data text field would be the same.

For further information regarding these and the rest constructors of `SelectList`, please have a look [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.selectlist(v=vs.118).aspx).

The in the View, you have to make another change.

This

```
 @Html.DropDownList("Userlist", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control"})
```

should be written like this:

```
 @Html.DropDownList("Userlist", ViewBag.Customerlist as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>,htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control"})
```

The constructor you use here is the following:

```
public static MvcHtmlString DropDownList(
    this HtmlHelper htmlHelper,
    string name,
    IEnumerable<SelectListItem> selectList,
    IDictionary<string, object> htmlAttributes
)
```

So, if you pass as the second argument the null, there isn't any select list. For further information regarding this html helper, please have a look [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.selectextensions.dropdownlist(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.Html.SelectExtensions.DropDownList%28System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper,System.String,System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable%7BSystem.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem%7D,System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary%7BSystem.String,System.Object%7D%29). Last but not least, please note the use of the `as` operator. We use it because we have to convert our object to a certain type, `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`, in order to pass it as an argument to our html helper. The `ViewData` is `ViewDataDictionary` type, which is among other things a `IDictionary<string, object>`. So this is why you have to convert your the `ViewBag.Userlist`.